# How to check if any activity is running?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I want to handle a behavior where user clicks on GCM notification. And i want to handle it differently in two situations: where the application is not running(there is no foreground and background activities in the stack) and the application is running and at least one activity is in the stack. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Determining if your Android Application is in Background or Foreground](http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html) is the most reliable method that I have come across. As explained in that article and elsewhere there are lot's of different ways for doing this, but using [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) as described is usually very reliable. It keeps count of number of activities started and if the number is greater than 1, your app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

In my senario I changed the NotificationReciever.
in "onPushReceive" method which comes from  ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. (I used parse for push). In your senario whre to detect the notification recieve.

```
   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
                    .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            boolean isActivityFound = false;

            if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
                isActivityFound = true;
            }

            if (isActivityFound) {
                //app is running
             return;
            } else {
                // applicaiton is not open, notification can come
                super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
            }
```

Comment: services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName(). Will It handle the situation where the application activity is on background?

Comment: ouhh sorry I misunderstand the question. This is not your question's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the classic method defining a `static` variable within the `Activity`.

```
class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     static boolean isActive = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         isActive = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         isActive = false;
      }
}
```

Comment: I want to check if any activity is running, not the concrete activity.

Comment: @SemGnil then make MyActivity a base class for all your activities, and instead of using isActive - make it an int which is incremented in onStart and decremented in onStop, then if isActive is 0 then no activity is shown.